# How do I cook any recipe with frozen eggplant?

Tags: frozen, eggplant

Four days ago I cut the ends off of a one pound eggplant, sliced it lengthwise, spread 1/4 tsp. of salt on each half, and left at room temperature (approx 65 degrees) for five hours.  Then I soaked up the liquid and brushed off each piece with paper towels.  At that point, I placed both pieces in a zip-close freezer (gallon) bag.  Now, do I thaw completely before using?  Thaw partially?  Cook straight from the freezer?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thawing would give you more consistent cooking times, if nothing else.  In some preparations (eg, frying), it'd also stop you from starting a massive fire.

Answer (score 2):

If the slices are thin, you could bake/roast straight from frozen. I do believe the texture will be quite soft so use a parchment lined sheet if you wish to roast it. I like to brush a bit of miso mixed with honey on roasted eggplants.

Another option would be to lay it into a lasagna. I think this option is the most appealing. I wouldn't bother to thaw it if your slices are under half an inch thick.

If you sliced it only in half, such that you have two "boat" shaped halves, I would thaw it fully first. It'll take a while to thaw in such large pieces. Baba ganoush would be a good option in this case.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you must thaw the eggplant completely.  Dry it off.  Then fry it up but since I am not supposed to give you a receipe, I would fry up onions, garlic, red peppers and other colors, anaheim chili peppers, all very soft, and some other veges you think may go good with this like carrots and celery and once that is done chop up the in nice cubes of the eggplants, fry them up till tender, add tomatoes or stewed tomatoes, more garlic, salt and pepper, a touch of jalapeno or chili flakes, then let everything on low and slow for about an hour, a little parsley and you should have something very delicious.  Next time don't freeze the eggplant and I do hope this all turns out very tasty for you.  You can also put on some plain yogurt on top mixed with some dill or mint, not both or even garlic.  Fry in canola oil only, eat hot or cold.